# How to apply vue module without CDN to html

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

I want to add a page composed of Vue to a project implemented in JavaScript.
It is said that you can add it using a CDN address, but the Vue function I want to use doesn't seem to support it.
What we want to use is element-tiptap.

This is the address of the function you want to use.

https://github.com/Leecason/element-tiptap

The above addresses do not provide a CDN.

You need to use element-ui and install element-tiptap.
But i don't know how to implement it via npm install.

The code below is a basic example of configuring el-tiptap.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<header>
  <img
    src="https://github.com/Leecason/element-tiptap/raw/master/examples/assets/logo_for_github.png?raw=true"
    height="50"
    class="logo"
  >
  
  <iframe
    src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=Leecason&repo=element-tiptap&type=star&count=true"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="0"
    width="95"
    height="20px"
  ></iframe>
</header>

<Editor/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from "./components/Editor";

export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        Editor
    }
};
</script>

<style>
    #app {
     font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
     color: #2c3e50;
     margin: 40px;
    }

header {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**Editor.vue**

```
<template>
  <el-tiptap :extensions="extensions" :content="content" placeholder="Write something ..."/>
</template>

<script>
import {
  // all extensions
  Doc,
  Text,
  Paragraph,
  Heading,
  Bold,
  Italic,
  Strike,
  Underline,
  Link,
  Image,
  Blockquote,
  ListItem,
  BulletList, // use with ListItem
  OrderedList, // use with ListItem
  TodoItem,
  TodoList, // use with TodoItem
  TextAlign,
  Indent,
  HorizontalRule,
  HardBreak,
  History
} from "element-tiptap";

import codemirror from "codemirror";
import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css"; // import base style
import "codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"; // language
import "codemirror/addon/selection/active-line.js"; // require active-line.js
import "codemirror/addon/edit/closetag.js"; // autoCloseTags

export default {
  name: "Editor",

  data: () => ({
    extensions: [
      new Doc(),
      new Text(),
      new Paragraph(),
      new Heading({ level: 5 }),
      new Bold({ bubble: true }),
      new Underline({ bubble: true }),
      new Italic({ bubble: true }),
      new Strike({ bubble: true }),
      new Link({ bubble: true }),
      new Image(),
      new Blockquote(),
      new TextAlign(),
      new ListItem(),
      new BulletList({ bubble: true }),
      new OrderedList({ bubble: true }),
      new TodoItem(),
      new TodoList(),
      new Indent(),
      new HardBreak(),
      new HorizontalRule({ bubble: true }),
      new Fullscreen(),
      new CodeView({
        codemirror,
        codemirrorOptions: {
          styleActiveLine: true,
          autoCloseTags: true
        }
      }),
      new History()
    ],

    content: ``
  })
};
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import { ElementTiptapPlugin } from 'element-tiptap';
import 'element-tiptap/lib/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.use(ElementTiptapPlugin, {
  // lang: "ko",
  // spellcheck: false,
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And I want to implement the above function here.

**editor.ejs**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #app {
      font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin: 40px;
    }
    
    header {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="app">
    <header>
      <img
        src="https://github.com/Leecason/element-tiptap/raw/master/examples/assets/logo_for_github.png?raw=true"
        height="50"
        class="logo"
      >
      
      <iframe
        src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=Leecason&repo=element-tiptap&type=star&count=true"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="0"
        width="95"
        height="20px"
      ></iframe>
    </header>
    <div>
        <!-- I would like to use this part. -->
        <el-tiptap :extensions="extensions" :content="content" placeholder="Write something ..."/>    
    </div>
  </div>
</body> 
<script> 
        //Something
</script> 
</html>
```

**I want it to work like this**

[image]

How should I implement it?
Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

Comment: Most libraries on npm have cdn versions of them available. Just search for <library_name> cdn, ensure it is the correct one and use it. If the library you want is a Vue project you can also clone it and use the vue-cli to build yourself a version you can host yourself. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html

Comment: @Chirag Ravindra
The tiptap at the address above is different from element-tiptap.
element-tiptap library doesn't seem to provide a CDN

Comment: you're right. You need element-tiptap only if you are already using element (including element to use tip-tap may be overkill). If you must have it, you can build yourself a version from the code using vue-cli. Also, the examples shared here are the official examples - it will help us understand your setup if you can share your code which tries reproducing this scenario minimally (like on codepen or jsbin)

Comment: @Chirag Ravindra
thank you for your answer.
Can I use vue with that cdn on existing html?